# Simple way to split a triangle into equal sub-triangles

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to split a triangle in half. The triangle can be rotated in anyway but can always be split equally in half (its an isosceles triangle not equilateral).

I have come up with an idea of how I can split a triangle of any rotation into 2 sub-triangles but its naive and needs to check which rotation the triangle is.

Is there a simpler way to split a triangle in half?

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve. Image 1 is my original triangles, then my function will run on each triangle to produce image 2 then my function will run again on each triangle and produce image 3.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
def split_triangle_evenly(tri_pts):
    # Pre: tri_pts[1] will always be the split point
    # ie, tri_pts[1] is the right-angle 
    half_tri1 = None
    half_tri2 = None
    break_x = tri[1][0]
    break_y = tri[1][1]

    # Naive technique that needs to check the rotation of the triangle
    # in order to figure out how to split it
    # is there a simplier way?
    if break_x > tri[0][0] and break_x > tri[2][0]:
        half_tri1 = (
            tri[0],
            (tri[0][0], break_y),
            tri[1]
        )
        half_tri2 = (
            tri[2],
            (tri[0][0], break_y),
            tri[1]
        )
    elif break_x < tri[0][0] and break_x < tri[2][0]:
        ...
    elif ...

    return (half_tri1, half_tri2)
```

Comment: Will your triangles always be right-angled isoceles? Because it will not work otherwise.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon if I understand your question, then no, the first image shows my triangles are not right angled and I need to split those.

Comment: @JakeM but in your first image your triangles are right angled ... the angle in the center is ninety degrees.

Comment: @MarkTyler woops yes you are correct. I misunderstood. Then yes, they will always be one right angle in the isosceles triangle. And to make it easier the triangle points passed to the function is always organised so the 'split' point (right angle) is at index 1 `tri_pnts[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have isosceles triangle with  break vertex `tri_pnts[1]`, then for any orientation break point at opposite side is

```
 breakpnt[0] = (tri_pnts[0][0]  + tri_pnts[2][0]) / 2
 breakpnt[1] = (tri_pnts[0][1]  + tri_pnts[2][1]) / 2

        half_tri1 = (
            tri[0],
            breakpnt,
            tri[1]
        )
        half_tri2 = (
            tri[1],
            breakpnt,
            tri[2]
        )
```

because median of isosceles triangle divides it into two similar triangles.

Do you need to provide specific orientation of resulting triangle vertices? This code gives similar orientation for both triangles (or CW or CCW) - if it is important...

Comment: thanks :) I'm not sure what you mean by `Do you need to provide specific orientation of resulting triangle vertices?` can you explain simply?

Comment: I do need to provide the 3 new vertices for each of the 2 new sub-triangles though. Are you able to update your answer to suggest how to calculate these in a simple manor?

Comment: Yoy already have code for filling new triangle, I just changed middle parens to new point and changred order. Now resulting triangles will have both clockwise or CCW orientation - I don't know if it importamt for your purposes.